# How to calculate frequency of residue(nucleotide) coverage in each column in R?

Tags: r, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a *fasta* file with data set like below:

```
>sequence_1
ACCTGC--A
>sequence_2
ACC-GCTTA
>sequence_3
ACCTGCTTA
```

The end goal is to produce results which indicate the percentage of nucleotide coverage. Hence, I would get 100%, 100%, 100%, 66.66%, 100%, 100%, 66.66%, 66.66$, 100%.

I am fairly new to R, my thinking right now is to read the sequences in as a string, then convert to lists, then loop through the first element of all the lists and so no.

Is there a easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution with `strsplit`.

`Biostrings` makes reading the `.fasta` file trivial. Note that this approach requires the sequences to already be aligned.

```
#BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
library(Biostrings)
data <- readDNAStringSet("data.fasta")
split <- strsplit(as.character(data),"")
logical.mat <- sapply(split, function(x) x != "-")
rowSums(logical.mat) / ncol(logical.mat)
#[1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

No experience with the bio-packages.. so here is a `data.table` approach of things...

```
library( data.table )
DT <- data.table( text = c( "ACCTGC--A", "ACC-GCTTA", "ACCTGCTTA" ))

#         text
# 1: ACCTGC--A
# 2: ACC-GCTTA
# 3: ACCTGCTTA

#split text to nucleoid
#get maximum number of nucleoid
n_max = length( tstrsplit(gsub("(.)", "\\1 ", DT$text), " ") )
#create a new column for each nucleoid
DT[, paste0( "nucl_", 1:n_max ) := tstrsplit(gsub("(.)", "\\1 ", text), " ") ]
#         text nucl_1 nucl_2 nucl_3 nucl_4 nucl_5 nucl_6 nucl_7 nucl_8 nucl_9
# 1: ACCTGC--A      A      C      C      T      G      C      -      -      A
# 2: ACC-GCTTA      A      C      C      -      G      C      T      T      A
# 3: ACCTGCTTA      A      C      C      T      G      C      T      T      A
                           
#how to procees? possibly melt and summarise?
DT.melt <- melt(DT, id.vars = "text", measure.vars = patterns("^nucl") )
ans <- DT.melt[, .N, by = .(variable, value) ][, perc := N / sum(N), by = .(variable)][]

#     variable value N      perc
# 1:    nucl_1     A 3 1.0000000
# 2:    nucl_2     C 3 1.0000000
# 3:    nucl_3     C 3 1.0000000
# 4:    nucl_4     T 2 0.6666667
# 5:    nucl_4     - 1 0.3333333
# 6:    nucl_5     G 3 1.0000000
# 7:    nucl_6     C 3 1.0000000
# 8:    nucl_7     - 1 0.3333333
# 9:    nucl_7     T 2 0.6666667
# 10:   nucl_8     - 1 0.3333333
# 11:   nucl_8     T 2 0.6666667
# 12:   nucl_9     A 3 1.0000000
```